# I can't connect to my system in some pc of the workgroup

Tags: php, mysql, appserver

Well , i have Appserv appserv-win32-2.5.10 installed in the server and i have a System in Php and mysql.
Some computers of the workgroup Can't enter to my system ,get a slow charge of the system an never finish.

Please Help
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Check their firewalls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your httpd.conf Apache file, in the directory tag, you should try something like this:

```
<Directory "/www/your_webroot">
 order allow,deny
 allow from all
</Directory>
```

The allow from all, should works ;)

PS: Here is a nice example of httpd.conf file:
http://www.devside.net/guides/config/windows/httpd-conf